# Is there a way to use a Ruby loop inside of HAML's :javascript region?

Tags: javascript, ruby, loops, haml, erb

Inside of HAML, can we have a loop inside the :javascript region?

This will work:

```
- 10.upto(20) do |i|
  :javascript
    document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML += '#{i}';
```

and this will not:

```
:javascript
  - 10.upto(20) do |i|
    document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML += '#{i}';
```

can the code above also be made to work as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this one works

```
%script
  - 10.upto(20) do |i|
    document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML += '#{i}';
```

Comment: works.  although type='text/javascript' and CDATA is missing, it still works.

Answer (score 14):

```haml
%html
  %head
    :javascript
      var foo = [];
      #{
        limit = rand(4)+3
        array = (0..limit).to_a
        array.map{ |i| "foo[#{i}] = #{rand(12)};" }.join ' '
      }
      console.log(foo.length);
    %body
```

Running the above code gives this output:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[
        var foo = [];
        foo[0] = 2; foo[1] = 0; foo[2] = 11; foo[3] = 8; foo[4] = 0; foo[5] = 1;
      //]]>
    </script>
    <body></body>
  </head>
</html>
```

As you can see, the big `#{...}` block (which may span multiple lines) runs arbitrary Ruby code. The result of the last expression (in this case the `map{...}.join`) is converted to a string and placed in the output.

**Edit for Radek**: If you want to declare a variable inside you Haml template, inside your JavaScript filter (which seems like an odd desire), then you need to be sure that the result of the block `to_s` doesn't produce unwanted output:

This Haml...

```haml
%p
  :javascript
    var foo = 12;
    #{x = 42}
    var bar = #{x};
```

...produces this HTML:

```
<p>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
      var foo = 12;
      42
      var bar = 42;
    //]]>
  </script>
</p>
```

Whereas this Haml...

```
%p
  :javascript
    var foo = 12;
    #{x = 42; ""}
    var bar = #{x};
```

...produces this HTML...

```
<p>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
      var foo = 12;

      var bar = 42;
    //]]>
  </script>
</p>
```

But before you do this, ask yourself: why am I creating complex Ruby variables in my view?
**Shouldn't this variable have been declared by my controller?**

Comment: what if I just want to define a variable? inside `:javascript` block?

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add that the following gets you the type and CDATA, but without the funky behaviour of :javascript (I just had to implement something like this).

```
%script{ :type => 'text/javascript' }
  \//<![CDATA[
  - (10..20) do |i|
    document.getElementById('aDiv').innerHTML += '#{i}';
  \//]]>
```