# How can I run an each block from within HAML's :javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I decided to update my templating technology to HAML. I'm new to it, and wondered if this is possible at all:

```
:javascript    
  <% @checkins.each do |checkin| %>
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= checkin.latitude %>, <%= checkin.longitude %>);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng, 
        map: map,
        title: '<%= escape_javascript(checkin.title) %>'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      document.location = '<%= checkin_path(checkin) %>';
    });    
  <% end %>
```

It's easy to see that the parts of the code I'm having problems with are the ones related to Ruby code

```
<% @checkins.each do |checkin| %>
```

or

```
document.location = '<%=checkin_path(checkin) %>';
```

I tried to change the latter to:

```
- @checkins.each do |checkin|
```

but it's not working out so far. I already read many other questions here about the same topic, but I haven't really been able to find a 'straight-forward' answer.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864500/how-to-run-ruby-in-haml-in-javascript-definition

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a Ruby loop inside of HAML's :javascript region?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962119/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-ruby-loop-inside-of-hamls-javascript-region)

Comment: Yes, those are similar question I did read before posting, but like I said did not address the issue directly IMHO. sorry,

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `<% @checkins.each do |checkin| %>` with

```
#{ @checkins.each.do |checkin|
```

and replace your `end` statement with `}`

Also replace your `<%= %>` with just `checkin.whateverproperty`

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something because with that change, I get new errors in the following JavaScript lines.
ie. syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(checkin.latitude...
... and more.

Comment: Try simplfying the loop and just do like var mytext= "Bob" if that works then it's the place where you are including the checkin.whateverproperty...I think the syntax for that is like #{checkin.whateverproprty}